# Not receiving Emails from php code

Tags: php

Not receiving emails. This is driving me NUTS, the original problem,
before with just the field. Email, subject, message. I was getting
emails, But I was unable to see the email variable. It just came in,
from my server. So I cannot reply to any emails I receive. thought to
add another field. "email again" but it says it is sending the email,
and I receive nothing in my inbox. What is the issue here? (note:
emailfieldtaken out for security reasons)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>testing</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #F7F3F3;
}
body {
    background-color: #050505;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
<?php ?>
<br />
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
{
    //excute the code
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $eg = $_POST['eg'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (strlen($email) <= 0)
        {
        echo "You need to enter an email";
    }else{
        if (strlen($subject) <= 0)
            {echo "You need to enter a subject";
        }else{
                        if (strlen($message) <= 0)
                    {echo "You need to enter a message";
            }else{
                            if (strlen($eg) <= 0)
                        {echo "Email Again";
                }else{
                    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true){
                    //continue with code
                    mail("random@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $eg,  "From:$email");
                    echo "Your message has been sent";
                    }
                        else
                            {
                        echo "You must fill out the entire form";
                            }
                     }
                }
            }
}
}
}
?>
<br />
<span style="text-align: center">This is the contact form.</span>
<form method="post" action="testing.php">
  <table align="center" style="color: #030303;">
<tr><td>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
<trd><td>Email Again:<input type="text" name="eg" /></td></tr>
<trd><td>Subject:<input type="text" name="subject" /></td></tr>
<trd><td><label for="textarea">Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="15">Type your message here.</textarea></tr><tr>
  <trd><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: There are many things that don't make sense in your code, like `(strlen($email) <= 0)` ***Fix*** them up! and it will work

Comment: @Simon_eQ agreed! Try if(!empty($email)){ for those kinds of checks.

Comment: If you are on a hosted server it might be a problem to use a "foreign" domain as sender (if i get your example correct its the form user's email adress that are set as sender in -f parameter), some hosts doesnt allow that. You should also check if safe_mode is active in php.ini. If so, you arent allowed to set the 5'th additional parameter (-f) at all. mail() will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `<tr>` tags, it might cause problem

```
<trd><td>Email Again:<input type="text" name="eg" /></td></tr>
   ^
<trd><td>Subject:<input type="text" name="subject" /></td></tr>
   ^
<trd><td><label for="textarea">Message:</label>
   ^
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="15">Type your message here.</textarea></tr><tr>
  <trd><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" /></td></tr>
     ^
```

proper way is

```
<tr><td>Email Again:<input type="text" name="eg" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject:<input type="text" name="subject" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="textarea">Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="15">Type your message here.</textarea></tr><tr>
  <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: changed the Trd to Tr. Same problem. Not receiving Emails.

Comment: the construction of layout elements won't play a part in the functionality of php's mail function inless the html in question is the fields themselves. But good catch anyhow

Comment: <tr><td>Email Again:<input type="text" name="eg" /></td></tr>
 I still have this line in and I'd like to keep it, in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a post field `$_POST['eg']` as mail headers. That will invariably cause a problem of some kind.

```
mail("random@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $eg,  "From:$email");
```

should be

```
mail("random@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "From:$email");
```

remove that `$eg` parameter. 4th position is for the header string. 5th can be additional parameters, but I think you might want to look into what that actually means. See the docs here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Update:

```
$header = "Reply-To: username@webhosting400.myserver.net\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

mail("random@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: Thank Kai, I'll give it a shot. This is my first baby step into PHP.

Comment: Receiving emails, cannot reply to emails. username@webhosting400.myserver.net Return address is.

Comment: You need to specify the reply-to header info. I updated with a quick example.

Comment: Well... It kinda makes it into the inbox.A message that you sent contained a recipient address that was incorrectly
constructed:

  From:email@yahoo.com  missing or malformed local part (expected word or "<")

The message has not been delivered to any recipients.

------ This is a copy of your message, including all the headers. ------

Comment: add the From: xxx@yyy.com part to the header. If the domain doesnt match the sending domain you may be seen as spam

Comment: maybe it wants the email like: xxx@yyy.com <some name>

Comment: I'm not sure, this is frustrating.

Comment: I think I need some one on one hands on. <--- You did this wrong. Let me show you how to fix it. *facepalm*